# PowerShell Passing Variables

Tags: powershell

I am attempting to call a function in powershell, but pass it variables so I don't need to repeat the funxtion X amount of times with different values. I would like it so that, when I call the function I simply type:

```
Foo(Red,12,1.8)
```

And the generic function, foo, as follows:

```
function Foo(Colour, Age, Height){
      <# Function does something with data here #>
}
```

Is this possible using powershell, and if so, would any changes made to those variables be saved after the function has completed?

Comment: The calling syntax would be `Foo Red 12 1.8` or `Foo -Colour Red -Age 12 -Height 1.8`, but otherwise yes, PowerShell has parameterized functions. Changes to declared parameters inside the function will _not_ be reflected in the calling scope by default though. Could you perhaps describe your use case? Why do you expect you need to call `Foo` multiple times?

Comment: Thank you, with use case I just realised this whole thing may not work, as I need to pass it different global variables each time and change those exact global variables.

Comment: You need to pass the arguments to your function as references and setup your function to accept references. See: Get-Help about_ref.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can use parameters in functions.

By default the parameters only change within the scope of the function, but you can choose to return the same parameters as results if you like.

example (uses splatting)-

```
function Foo{
    param(
        [string]$Color,
        [int]$Age,
        [decimal]$Height
    )
    $Age += 1
    $Height += 1

    $ExampleOutput = [ordered]@{
        Color = $Color
        Age = $Age
        Height = $Height
    }
    return ($ExampleOutput)
}

$Parameters = @{
  Color = "Red"
  Age = 12
  Height = 1.8
}

Foo @Parameters
```

Comment: Thank you, I have however realised I now need to be able to pass it 3 sets of global variables, each with the same function but for 3 separate systems (For example, Age1,Age2,Age3), have it use and change those variables and then return them again...I feel like this answer gets the closest, so how would I achieve the above? Thanks

Comment: You could potentially just use my example with a larger hash table or array of hashi tables. Other options are accessing global variables from functions, or building a class.

Answer (score 1):

Yes try default values:

```
function Foo($Colour='Red',$Age=12,$Height=1.8){
      <# Function does something with data here #>
}
```